# Can I invest in both SEP IRA and IRA or solo 401(k) if i've worked in W2 for few months and as an independent contractor for the rest of the year?

Tags: united-states, 401k, roth-ira, self-employment, roth-401k

I worked as a W-2 employee from Jan-Mar and became an independent contractor from Sep this year.My employer did not provide me 401(k) or any benefits. I received around 18K after tax from W2 and I'm expecting around 47K as independent contractor. I'm planning to invest in SEP IRA which would be 47k * 25% = 11K. Can I invest my W2 salary for retirement fund, if yes how and how much can I contribute.

Note: I'm new to this, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're able to have both.  See [this explanation](https://www.fool.com/knowledge-center/can-a-person-have-a-401k-and-sep-ira-simultaneousl.aspx) for example.

> Finally, if you have a 401(k) through an employer and have a SEP IRA for your self-employment income, each contribution is treated separately. You can defer up to $18,000 of your salary into your 401(k) and your total contribution is limited to $53,000 ($59,000 if over 50) after your employer contributes, as discussed earlier. Since your SEP IRA contributions are considered to come from the employer, none of it counts toward the $18,000 salary deferral limit, so you can contribute up to $53,000 or 25% of your earnings, whichever is less.

The amounts here are a bit old; [19k is now the max for your own contributions](https://www.irs.gov/newsroom/401k-contribution-limit-increases-to-19000-for-2019-ira-limit-increases-to-6000), and [56k is now the max for the employer contributions](https://www.irs.gov/retirement-plans/how-much-can-i-contribute-to-my-self-employed-sep-plan-if-i-participate-in-my-employers-simple-ira-plan).

So in your case your limits are your total W2 income (up to 19k max) in your W2 employer's 401(k), and 25% of your contracting income, or $11,750, to the Solo 401(k) or SEP IRA (both of which use the 56k max).

Comment: The contribution limits in this article are a couple years old. Also be sure to differentiate between a W-2 employer 401(k) and a Solo 401(k).

Comment: @CraigW Thanks for pointing that out, I've updated with the proper amounts.  I think the article quote covers that, but I added some language to clarify.